# MPMoviePlayerViewController playing movie only in landscape mode

Tags: iphone

I want to play the video only in landscape mode in iPhone SDK.40(MPMoviePlayerViewController). It should not support portrait mode play back. How do we do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

So basically you just need to create your own subclass of MPMoviePlayerViewController and override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method, like so:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
{  
     return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);  
}
```

Comment: @andrew: i use your method too, but sometime it still playvideo in Portrait mode